# Download API JSON file in R and convert to dataframe

Tags: r, json, url, request

I'm trying to pull down the JSON file from the NASDAQ request URL in **R** but I've been unsuccessful.  I've been able to craft a solution in Python but I'm really interested in finding a solution in **R**, if possible.

I've reached out to the NASDAQ helpdesk and accessing the data via the request API URL is not something they support.

I've seen several solutions in Stack Overflow but none of them appear to work with my particular situation.  Here is the simplest attempt and the result I received:

```
library(jsonlite)
data <- fromJSON('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/dividends?date=2023-10-09')

Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
```

I don't believe the above attempt is the correct approach, so I'm hoping someone sees this and has a solution that will work.

My expected result is the JSON file would be extracted from the request API URL (https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/dividends?date=2023-10-09) and converted into an **R** dataframe.

Comment: It works for me, so your problem might be one of: (1) spurious network glitch, on your end, their end, or something in between ... but temporary; (2) your network is filtering out some connections for whatever reason, whether corporate policy or related; (3) they (NASDAQ) have geo-ip filters, and you happen to be in one they don't know to trust/allow.

Comment: Thanks for the response r2evans.  So, you are able to run the code with no issues and it returns the result in an R dataframe?  The odd thing to me is I'm able to pull the data down in JSON when I write it in python.

Comment: It retrieved a nested list. It will take extra code to convert this into a frame, but it is certainly possible to do so. I get no errors when downloading it, it has a status code of 200 (normal/good). (This is an image of it, just to show you what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzfqe.png).

Comment: Are you on windows? If so, check `options("url.method")`, and/or try explicitly using `fromJSON(url("https://...", method="default"))`, cycling through the alternatives for `method=` given in [`?url`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html). (Even if not on windows, perhaps one of the alternatives will work when `"default"` does not.)

Comment: Thanks for the recommended approaches.  Yes, I'm on windows.  Tried data <- fromJSON(url('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/dividends?date=2023-10-09',method="default")) and received the same error message.  Will try some of the other options to see if I can't get it to work.  So, I wonder if python uses a different port than R does for the http api calls?

Comment: I tried several variations of the following:  library(jsonlite)
data <- fromJSON(url('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/dividends?date=2023-10-09',blocking=TRUE,encoding=getOption("encoding"),method=getOption("url.method","default")))
, but I haven't had any luck.  I think you may be onto something with regards to my ports being blocked when I use R, which would explain why I'm able to successfully execute a similar program in python effectively.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to diagnoise what port is being used in python vs. R and how to remedy the issue.

Comment: Which of the `url(method=)` options did you try? The fact that python works and R doesn't more strongly suggests that it's the method that's doing it. Though it is technically possible for your personal firewall to block R and allow python, it is less common to see that.

Comment: I completely agree that it's probably the method that is causing the issue.  These were the url(method=) options that i tried:  default, internal, wininet, and libcurl.

Comment: Any additional troubleshooting ideas I can try?  I'm out of ideas.  Spent some time looking at my ports, running various alterations to my original code snippet, reached out to my ISP, attempted to run the code from another wifi network, utilizing the reticulate package to run my python code that works within R  etc., etc. and I can't get anything to work.

Comment: Nothing yet. I've tried `httr`, `httr2`, `rvest`, even going direct to `curl`, and all of them err with `HTTP/2 stream # was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)`, meaning something on the server end (I believe) is not behaving as CURL would like. After trying to override the HTTP version using `httr::GET(.., httr::config(http_version=2L))` (the `2L` is an enum, not the version number itself), it hangs and never returns (for me). Not at all sure what's going on there, but perhaps it works for you? `res <- httr::GET("https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/dividends?date=2023-10-09")`

Comment: Thanks again for the additional look r2evans.  Over the last few weeks I've tried several attempts with httr with no success.  My python code, that ran successful included headers in the api call.  When I removed the headers from my python script it just hung, so I wonder if there's something to that.  I tried multiple attempts to incorporate headers into my R code but haven't found a successful combination yet.  Maybe there's something to adding the headers to my R code?

Comment: url <- 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/dividends?date=2023-10-09'
response <- GET(url, add_headers(.headers = c(  'accept'= 'application/json, text/plain, */*','accept-encoding'= 'gzip, deflate, br',
       'accept-language'= 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
       'origin'= 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
       'referer'= 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
       'sec-fetch-mode'= 'cors',
      'User-Agent'= 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36')))

Comment: I'm hoping that works for you, your code worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the site is (intentionally?) hanging on some queries based on a header.

## TL;DR

```r
library(httr)
url <- 'api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/dividends?date=2023-10-09'
response <- GET(url, add_headers(
  `User-Agent`= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"
  ,`Accept-Language`= "en-US,en;q=0.5"
))
status_code(response)
# [1] 200
str(content(response))
# List of 3
#  $ data   :List of 2
#   ..$ calendar :List of 3
#   .. ..$ asOf   : chr "Mon, Oct 9, 2023"
#   .. ..$ headers:List of 8
#   .. .. ..$ symbol                   : chr "Symbol"
#   .. .. ..$ companyName              : chr "Name"
#   .. .. ..$ dividend_Ex_Date         : chr "Ex-Dividend Date"
#   .. .. ..$ payment_Date             : chr "Payment Date"
#   .. .. ..$ record_Date              : chr "Record Date"
#   .. .. ..$ dividend_Rate            : chr "Dividend"
#   .. .. ..$ indicated_Annual_Dividend: chr "Indicated Annual Dividend"
#   .. .. ..$ announcement_Date        : chr "Announcement Date"
#   .. ..$ rows   :List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :List of 8
#   .. .. .. ..$ companyName              : chr "Brady Corporation Common Stock"
#   .. .. .. ..$ symbol                   : chr "BRC"
#   .. .. .. ..$ dividend_Ex_Date         : chr "10/09/2023"
#   .. .. .. ..$ payment_Date             : chr "10/31/2023"
#   .. .. .. ..$ record_Date              : chr "10/10/2023"
#   .. .. .. ..$ dividend_Rate            : num 0.235
#   .. .. .. ..$ indicated_Annual_Dividend: num 0.94
#   .. .. .. ..$ announcement_Date        : chr "9/04/2023"
#   .. .. ..$ :List of 8
#   .. .. .. ..$ companyName              : chr "Saba Capital Income & Opportunities Fund SBI"
#   .. .. .. ..$ symbol                   : chr "BRW"
#   .. .. .. ..$ dividend_Ex_Date         : chr "10/09/2023"
#   .. .. .. ..$ payment_Date             : chr "10/31/2023"
#   .. .. .. ..$ record_Date              : chr "10/10/2023"
#   .. .. .. ..$ dividend_Rate            : num 0.085
#   .. .. .. ..$ indicated_Annual_Dividend: num 1.02
#   .. .. .. ..$ announcement_Date        : chr "9/29/2023"
#   ..$ timeframe:List of 2
#   .. ..$ minDate: chr "1922-05-22T00:00:00"
#   .. ..$ maxDate: chr "2104-06-02T00:00:00"
#  $ message: NULL
#  $ status :List of 3
#   ..$ rCode           : int 200
#   ..$ bCodeMessage    : NULL
#   ..$ developerMessage: NULL
```

I show the results from my headers, though in the end yours worked as well.

## How I Found This

In my Firefox browser, I sent to that URL and it immediately worked. Opening up the browser devtools (`F12`), going to the *Network* tab, right-clicking on the request row (that should show a 200) and selecting *Copy Value >> Copy Request Headers*, I got this:

```
GET /api/calendar/dividends?date=2023-10-09 HTTP/2
Host: api.nasdaq.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

(There was also a `Cookie:` header, but I removed it in the unlikely event it means something personal for me/my-browser *shrug*.)

I converted these into an R-friendly vector of string arguments with

```r
hdrs <- clipr::read_clip()
hdrs |>
  grep("^(GET|Host:) ", x = _, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE) |>
  sub("^([^:]+):", ", `\\1` =", x = _) |>
  paste(collapse = "\n") |>
  sub("^, ", "", x = _) |>
  cat("\n")
# `User-Agent` = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0
# , `Accept` = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
# , `Accept-Language` = en-US,en;q=0.5
# , `Accept-Encoding` = gzip, deflate, br
# , `Connection` = keep-alive
# , `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` = 1
# , `Sec-Fetch-Dest` = document
# , `Sec-Fetch-Mode` = navigate
# , `Sec-Fetch-Site` = cross-site
# , `Pragma` = no-cache
# , `Cache-Control` = no-cache
```

(my real console output doesn't have the `#` prepended), which I then copy/paste into a template expression that was

```r
response <- GET(url, add_headers(
  ###
))
status_code(response)
```

overwriting the `###` with the `cat`'ed headers. I ran it and immediately got a `200`, meaning it succeeded. I then removed all options and tried again, it hung (no surprise). I added a few at a time until I got a `200` again, ultimately coming up with the two headers that made a difference.

Ultimately I found what works (and I think your commented code is mostly the same).

## data.frame

I'll use `dplyr` here since it tends to work with list-columns better than base.

```r
library(dplyr)
quux <- content(response)
tibble(asOf = quux$data$calendar$asOf) %>%
  reframe(asOf, rows = lapply(quux$data$calendar$rows, as.data.frame)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(rows)
# # A tibble: 2 × 9
#   asOf             companyName                                  symbol dividend_Ex_Date payment_Date record_Date dividend_Rate indicated_Annual_Dividend announcement_Date
#   <chr>            <chr>                                        <chr>  <chr>            <chr>        <chr>               <dbl>                     <dbl> <chr>            
# 1 Mon, Oct 9, 2023 Brady Corporation Common Stock               BRC    10/09/2023       10/31/2023   10/10/2023          0.235                      0.94 9/04/2023        
# 2 Mon, Oct 9, 2023 Saba Capital Income & Opportunities Fund SBI BRW    10/09/2023       10/31/2023   10/10/2023          0.085                      1.02 9/29/2023
```

I think the `quux$data$headers` is just a way to map the names found in `rows` with more-human-readable of the same, so it didn't add much. Similarly, `minDate` and `maxDate` may be nice for you to know, but perhaps not as important in the resulting frame.

There's likely a better way to frame-ize it, but this works for now and might be good-enough for getting at the data.

Comment: r2evans, that worked!  Thanks again for taking the time to help me out with this.  Great coloration!  Still a little puzzled why you were able to run my initial string of code without issue and what the headers are doing to complete the call.

Comment: Sometimes (often enough) it's due to something with the server end of things, whether it be HA (load balancing) or something else not measurable by the client. Either way, glad it works reliably for you.